# How to change counsel grep options once activated? (counsel-rg, counsel-git-grep ... etc)

Tags: counsel

I would like to have the ability to change the flags passed to grep once `counsel-rg` has been stated.

For example, sometimes I start `counsel-rg` and type in a string that needs a lot of escaping. In this case I'd like the ability to search for a string literal (with no regex).

Is there a way to change `counsel-rg-base-command` while counsel is already searching?

---

I assume the exact search back-end probably doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I also often have to search in my org documents for lines with words having emphasis. For example:

```
A sentence with a very *important* concept
```

As org-mode uses a star character to encompass bold words, just searching for `*important*` would trigger an error. As you said, you can decide to escape the query by typing `\*important\*` which can be cumbersome.

The alternative, is to specify ripgrep `-F` flag at end of the query prompt, by separating it with a double dash `--` : `*important* -- -F`.

Besides the `-F` flag I often use the `-v` flag to invert the matches and only search through results that do not contain the pattern.

Comment: Is there a way to toggle a command line argument, eg: `-F` with an already open search?